# Is there an "automated" process to altering SQL column names throughout code?

Tags: php, mysql

If one were to have a database that was used by a lot of different code, what would be the most practical process to disseminating database changes throughout?

I have a personal mysql database that I'm continually "evolving". However, I also have a lot of PHP code that's already established to use specific column names in this database. Other than manually finding/replacing column names throughout the code, is there an established method/way/process for altering column names and disseminating that throughout the code?

From my limited view, I imagine it might need to be approached from the language side of the equation, i.e., perhaps some type of extension functionality, like with PDO.

Perhaps just a "buffer" layer of defining the current database column names as variables at the beginning of the code is the simplest way?

Comment: If you use utilities like phpMyAdmin and have an existing database you can dump the **structure** of a database only. If I need to make massive database changes I usually craft a simple PHP script that does it for me. But that's just me!

Comment: Rails does this via 'Migrations'. I haven't come across anything like this in PHP, but I bet some library out there has attempted it.

Comment: I regularly check my entire database structure into git (structure, not data).  This makes it easier to change column names in one go via a search and replace, both data structure and code base.  Of course non-trivial changes (column semantics) will still require some kind of conversion query(ies).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do is to separate the *persistence of data* from how that data is used in your app. The structure of your database should not define the structure of your app. Inside your app, you pass data around via objects or defined array structures. At some specified point, you store these objects/arrays into the database because you want to persist them for later use. To do this you have one defined point where your data objects/arrays are put into the database and vice-versa. Which means this point is the only point where you are referring to database-specific names. If you need to change the database schema, you only need to update the thin layer that deals with database-object conversion; you won't need to update "the whole app" because the rest of the application refers to the naming of your defined data objects.

This is typically known as [Object-Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), [Data Access Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) and other related techniques.

```
+----------+ +-----+ +---...
|          | |     | |
| Database <-> DAL | | rest of your app...
|          | |     | |
+----------+ +-----+ +---...
```

The translation between the database structure and tangible data objects only happens in the DAL. The rest of the app just talks to the DAL to get or store data objects, it does not need to know or care what exactly the database structure looks like.

Comment: `The database is just there to persist data...` This is patently false. Databases are far more than just a blind persistence store, but unfortunately, ORMs tend to make people believe otherwise. **EDIT:** That shouldn't have been a downvote.

Comment: Meh, ok, that was a bit strongly worded. I meant the structure of the database should not define the data structure of your application.

Comment: Everything said about some intermediate layer is architecturally sound, and it can make it easier to change database names, but in a large project, even so it's a total pain to change database names.  Just less of a pain.  In any case, this is not the real reason to introduce intermediate layers.  It's just a helpful side-effect of doing so.

Comment: @DWright Agreed, if your app is complex enough, changing something as essential as the data store is always a pain. But properly compartmentalizing who relies on those names greatly minimizes the impact. It's basically the same argument for why global variables are bad. If every part of your app depends on a certain identifier name, every change to that identifier has ripple effects throughout everything.

Comment: @deceze.  Yeah, the fact that an identifier ripples through everything is a good sign of way too much coupling in the system.

Answer (score 0):

deceze is 100% right, this is the way to go. Here is an example of a DAL. It would be an a function that interacts with the database for you and returns an object you would expect such as:

```
function GetUser($id,$lname="",$fname="") {
      if ($id != -1)
         $m = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id");
      elseif ($lname != "" && $fname != "")
         $m = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where user_first_name='$fname' AND user_last_name='$lname'");
      elseif ($lname != "")
         $m = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where user_last_name='$lname'");
      elseif ($fname != "")
         $m = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where user_first_name='$fname'");
      if (!$m)
        return NULL;
      $r = mysql_fetch_row($m);
      $obj = new stdClass();
      $obj->id = $r[0];
      $obj->FirstName = $r[1];
      $obj->LastName = $r[2];
      return $obj;
}
```

The returned result would give you an object to interact with that you can add/change to and rely on to constantly have the results you want. You would only change the column names in this function then rather then the entire of your code.

Hope this helps shed some light on his answer.